# Why an Internal Server Error ? TypeError : float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'BoundField'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have created a movie renting app in Django 2.0 and Python 3.6. I am getting an error on BoundField and I am trying to add the new movie to the existing table in the database like movie_name and price. Bellow is mentioned code:

```
#module.py file
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm


class Customer(models.Model):
    f_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    l_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=125)
    cell = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)


class Movie(models.Model):
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    flag = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey('Customer', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

views.py code

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Customer, Movie
# from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import MovieForm, CustForm


def dashboard(request):
    customer_data = Customer.objects.all()
    context = {'Customer_List': customer_data}
    return render(request, 'movie_renting_app/home.html', context)


def movie_list(request):
    movie_data = Movie.objects.all()
    context = {"Movie_List": movie_data}
    return render(request, 'movie_renting_app/all_movies.html', context)


def rented_movies(request):
    rented_movie = Movie.objects.filter(flag=True)
    context = {"Rented_Movies_List": rented_movie}
    return render(request, 'movie_renting_app/rent.html', context)


def add_movies(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = MovieForm()
        print(request)
        m = Movie(genre=form['genre'], price=form['price'], flag=form['flag'])
        m.save()
        return movie_list(request)
    else:
        form = MovieForm()
        return render(request, 'movie_renting_app/new_movie.html', {'form': form})


def add_customer(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = request.POST
        print(request)
        c = Customer(f_name=form['f_name'], l_name=form['l_name'], address=form['address'], cell=form['cell'])
        c.save()
        return dashboard(request)
    else:
        form = CustForm()
        return render(request, 'movie_renting_app/new_customer.html', {'form': form})


def update_customer_info(request):
    pass


def available_list(request):
    pass
```

forms.py code

```
from django import forms
from .models import Movie


class MovieForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ['genre', 'price', 'flag']


class CustForm(forms.Form):
    f_name = forms.CharField(label='First_Name', max_length=50)
    l_name = forms.CharField(label='Last_Name', max_length=50)
    address = forms.CharField(label='Address', max_length=125)
    cell = forms.IntegerField(label='Cell')
```

I am attaching the command prompt[image: Internal Server Error] error. I have tried various ways to change the price value and even I am not sure what's wrong with my code. It says internal server error.

Comment: In views.py file, you assign form to MovieForm(), you need to set it to request.POST

Comment: Please post your errors as text in the question, not as tiny screenshots.

Comment: @abarnert if you click on the image it will open on a new tab and it will more clear to understand the error. Thank you

Comment: not only your form doesn't receive any `data` such as `request.POST`, the way you retrieve data from form is not good, take a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#the-view). you should consider master the process

Comment: @Lemayzeur Thank you. I'll take a look.

Comment: It's still not readable until I zoom in. And, even if I do that, there's no way for me to copy and paste information from your output to do a web search looking for the appropriate docs or other relevant information. Plus, not everyone wants to open multiple tabs, or open arbitrary pages from external sites. You're making it harder for people to help you, which inevitably means fewer people are going to try to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like this,

```
def add_movies(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = MovieForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            m = Movie(genre=form.cleaned_data['genre'], price=form.cleaned_data['price'], flag=form.cleaned_data['flag'])
            m.save()
            return movie_list(request)
        return HttpResponse("form is not valid")
    # your code
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

In `views.py` file, you assign the `form` to `MovieForm()`, you need to use it like below:

```
form = MovieForm(request.POST)
```

As @Lemayzeur mentioned, you need to look Django's documentation ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#the-view)) to learn how to validate and process data.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to know when you create a form, it probably means that you will pass data to it.

```
form = MovieForm() # initialize the form
```

You need to know that this form has been created with a Model, so it's like `MovieForm` was the Model Class itself, to create the instance, you just need to add data which come from the template via `request.POST`

```
form = MovieForm(request.POST) # or MovieForm(data=request.POST)
```

We're in the process to create the instance, but before that we can't allow any kind of values from the user, that's why `form.is_valid()` appears:

```
if request.POST:
    form = MovieForm(request.POST) # or MovieForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        ''' '''
```

Once the form is valid, we can retrieve all the value from `request.POST`, like `request.POST['price']`. This will work, but it's not recommended, retrieve the data from `form.cleaned_data` is better and safer because Django will convert any object to object type provided in form. For instance: If you had a form that contains a `BooleanField()`, a `Checkbox` will be generated in template. Now once submit, `request.POST.get('bool_field_name')` will return `"True"` or `"False"` as `string`. whereas Django will set up everything for you, and you would get the Boolean value as wanted. So we have:

```
if request.POST:
    form = MovieForm(request.POST) # or MovieForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        genre = form.cleaned_data.get('genre')
        ''' rest of the code '''
```

Since your form has been built with a `ModelForm`, you don't need to retrieve the data from `cleaned_data`, Django simplifies the process. You just need to save your form, and Django will automatically create the instance.

```
if request.POST:
    form = MovieForm(request.POST) # or MovieForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save() 
        # instance = form.save(commit=False) | will not save the instance
        # commit = False | in case you want to do something else before saving
        # By using commit = False, if you have m2mfield
        # You need to call save_m2m() - required if you use commit False.
```

Note `instance` variable is an instance of the Model passed in class `Meta` from your form.

```
class MovieForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ['genre', 'price', 'flag']
```

For further explanations, please refer to the [Official Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#the-view)

Comment: Thank you for your help.